# German special characters get stuck when submitting via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

I'm submitting parameters (including special characters like ä,ö,ü) via jquery.ajax to a results div. In that div I need to process it with php.

For example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/ajax.results.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: 'type='+$('#type').val()
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

In this example 'type' has the value 'Müller'. In my 'ajax.results.php' I do this:

```
<?= $_GET['type'] ?>

// Output is 'Müller' in Firefox and Chrome

// BUT in internet explorer the output is 'M'
```

So, it's fine for Firefox and Chrome, but in internet explorer the result is 'M' (M followed by a square)...

I've tried to change the output like this:

```
<?= utf8_encode($_GET['type'] ?>

// Output in internet Explorer now is fine (Müller)

// BUT in Firefox and Chrome it is 'MÃ¼ller'
```

As the output has to be via PHP (because I'll do further operations with it), I can't find a solution...

Can anyone please help to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Comment: And you saved the files in UTF8 as well.

Comment: And set a proper charset etc.

Comment: yes all file are utf8

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues in IE, unless it's not setting the charset to UTF8. IE defaults to 1252 if you're not setting it properly.

Comment: I've adittionally tried to set them with 'header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");'

Comment: And you added the meta tags to the head, like in  the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I found the solution myself: I've added 'encodeURIComponent()' to my ajax request and it works :-)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/ajax.results.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: 'type='+encodeURIComponent($('#type').val())
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

At the HTML page where you have the dropdown, insert

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

inside the  tag.

And be sure to save all your files as UTF-8 (or better: UTF-8 without BOM)

Apache servers are configured to serve files in ISO-8859-1 by default, so you need to add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: This is, what I already have... Still doens't work. Hmmm.. I'll try some alternative variations...